# Is there a term for a game whose pareto optimal solutions and nash equilibria are disjoint?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Is there a term for a game whose pareto optimal solutions and nash equilibria are disjoint?

(e.g. prisoner's dilemma)

Answer (score 1):

The term I often come across is 'inefficient Nash equilibrium' or 'Pareto-inefficient Nash equilibrium'. Here is an older well cited article discussing inefficient NEs: http://www.jstor.org/stable/3690047?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Here is the frequency of the term 'inefficient Nash equilibrium' used in scientific papers:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Inefficient+Nash+Equilibrium%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5

'Inefficient outcome' is also frequently used to describe NEs that are not Pareto-optimal: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Inefficient+outcome%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5
But it has to be put into game-theoretical context and specified that it is NE.

Comment: I think these terms do not quite fit. A single Nash equilibrium may be inefficient, but another Nash equilibrium may not be, in which case the two sets are not disjoint.

Comment: @HRSE I agree. It would make sense only for a game with either one NE (like prisoner's dilemma) or many NE's, all of which are inefficient. So maybe there is a room for a better answer if anyone came across anything more specific.

Comment: I propose that we begin referring to such games as exhibiting the "user2429920 property"

Comment: I propose "inefficient game".  Thoughts?